# Can I somehow get `Get-Content` cmdlet output into `ArrayList` object?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to cast output from `Get-Content myfile.txt` into an `ArrayList` object so that I can easily insert and change strings with `.add` and `.insert`. What I've tried is

```
[Systems.Collections.ArrayList]mylist=@()
Get-Content myfile | $mylist # obviously wrong
Get-Content myfile | ForEach-Object {$mylist} # don't quite grasp the logic, get empty array as a result
Get-Content myfile | ForEach-Object {$mylist.Add()} # get overload error
```

if I just assign `$mylist=Get-Content myfile.txt` it will change data type to static array which I don't want

Comment: `Get-Content myfile | ForEach-Object {$mylist.Add($_)}` you need to actually pass a value to `Add` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get-Content returns an array, so you can cast directly to an ArrayList:

```
$mylist = [System.Collections.ArrayList](Get-Content myfile)
$mylist.gettype()                                                                                                                                                                                       

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                        
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                        
True     False    ArrayList                                System.Object
```

Now you can modify with the `.add()` or `.insert()` methods like:

```
$mylist.insert(2,"new content")
```